# Disable 2nd row of UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

At the moment, I have a `UITableView` and with 2 rows. As shown in the picture. It is set up by an array in `ViewDidLoad`.

[image]

**ViewDidLoad**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

 [super viewDidLoad];
self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Analysis", @"Badminton Analysis Tool");
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Statistical Analysis", @"Graphical Analysis", nil];
self.booksArray = array;
}
```

**didSelectRowAtIndexPath**

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (self.statViewController == nil) {
    StatViewController *statDetail = [[StatViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StatViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.statViewController = statDetail;
}
statViewController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [booksArray objectAtIndex:row]];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:statViewController animated:YES];
}
```

At the moment, when I click on either rows, it pushes onto the same view that I intend only for 'Statistical Analysis'. I would like to disable clicking for Graphical Analysis. How can I disable selection for 'Graphical Analysis'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Return `nil` from your table view delegate's `-tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
        return nil;
    else
        return indexPath;
}
```

Comment: You have to add that to the delegate class of your UITableView.

Comment: Nice, it works. Thanks. But when I click on the 2nd row, it sometimes flashes. How can I disable the blue flash when I try to click on the 2nd row?

Comment: try [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

Comment: Upvoting and accepting answers also makes the blue flash appear slightly less stronger.

Comment: Hey, do I put here? - (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        return nil;
    else
        return indexPath;
}

Comment: Yes, but parenthesize the if-else branches, because the code as you typed it now won't work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10710/discussion-between-k-honda-and-h2co3)

Answer (score 1):

Implement tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath: (see documentation) and return nil if the path matches what you want disabled.

Comment: Hey Phillip, in relation to my code above. How can I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

You can deselect Row at index by using this:-
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

voting my answer and increase my reputation by up-voting arrow.

Comment: How can I deselect the Row at index in deselectRowAtIndexPath? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {  
      if(indexPath.row == 1) {
         [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
         return;
       }
}
```

Comment: Nice, it works. Thanks. But when I click on the 2nd row, it sometimes flashes. How can I disable the blue flash when I try to click on the 2nd row?

Answer (score 1):

For disableing the blue flash, do something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (cell == nil)     {
     //usually this is the place where we decide the selection style blue/none
```

}
 if(indexPath.row == 1) {
                   cell.setUserInteractionEnabled = NO;//this way the didSelectrow delegate method will not be called.
   else     {
 cell.setUserInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
return cell;
}
hope it would help you.

Answer (score 0):

## pragma mark -

## pragma mark Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  if (indexPath.row == 0)
  {

  ```
  iHadAppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  delegate.flag = 0;
  delegate.mytag = 0;

  TableSelectMealViewController *detail = 
  [[TableSelectMealViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  detail.rows = 6;   
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];
  SelectMealViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(285, 400);

  [detail release];
  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  ```

  }

  if (indexPath.row == 1)
  {
      iHadAppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      delegate.flag = 1;

  ```
  DatePickerViewController *controller = [[DatePickerViewController alloc]init];
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
  controller.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(285, 400);

  [controller release];
  ```

  }

  if (indexPath.row == 2)
  {
      iHadAppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      delegate.flag = 2;

  }

  if (indexPath.row == 3)
  {
      iHadAppDelegate *delegate =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      delegate.flag = 3;

  ```
  TableSelectMealViewController *detail = 
  [[TableSelectMealViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
  //detail.rows = 10;
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detail animated:YES];

  SelectMealViewController.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(285, 400);

  [detail release];
  [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
  ```

  }

}

@k.Honda take observations from my code.

```
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
```

use for -- where i want to deselect the row [ not for each row- only that row which i want to deselect].